# What if I got upvoted and the upvoter lost their upvote privilege?

Tags: support, upvotes, privileges

An upvote privilege is gained when a users has a reputation of 15 or more. But what if someone having the upvote privilege upvotes my answer and after that loses the privilege again? Will upvotes made by him be taken away? Will my reputation also fall by 10 times however many times he upvoted me?

Comment: I am not an SOF meta addict but I do not think you will lose the upvote. It will be there, but that user won't be able to upvote anymore.

Comment: Upvote remains. What makes things more funny: this upvoter will be able to _remove_ his previous upvote (in a time limit, or after your post is edited), but he won't be able to give it back.

Comment: Imagine the cascade of what could happen if it worked this way. The upvoter loses rep, so their upvotes are removed, causing you to lose rep so your upvotes are removed, causing the people you upvoted to lose rep, causing their upvotes to be removed, and so on.

Comment: _Imagine the cascade_ OMG, I just did and had a vision of SO going going gone and only Jon remaining

Comment: @TaW Amidst all the chaos, ruin and desolation, one stood strong!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If the user had the privilege when upvoting, then it was a valid upvote at the time.

It will not be taken away.

(this assumes valid voting - if vote fraud was involved, reputation can and will be taken away)

Comment: I'm curious, why is this case treated differently from a user account being deleted? I've lost upvotes a few times when the upvoting account was deleted.

Comment: @MichaelGeary - when a user is deleted, the votes go with them. It is like they never existed. A user the lost a privilege is still there; Consider the bounty system - easy to lose privileges by awarding lots of large bounties. Should any votes someone like that gave be gone?

Comment: @oded why delete an user at all? Can't an account be locked/anonymized? Assuming it wasn't a spam account or something...

Comment: An account on this community cannot be anonymised because they never care to remove personal details form their posts when they anonymise them. They should permanently delete the account and all data associated with it - like any normal website would. If the user no longer wishes to be involved in the community, and does not want the data _that they created_ to be there, they should always have that option.

Comment: @Jase Thats not true under the license you agreed to when you created the content.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I think you may have misinterpreted my comment. :-) I know what their terms are. But I know a few people who are really not OK with the terms and I can understand why. I don't like the general direction many companies are moving in these days. I don't believe that just because you post something on a website, you sign away your rights to it. In cases like SO, it's fine, because it can potentially help others. But with other services, it only exists to make them more money.

Comment: If someone is not OK with the terms, _they should not be posting here_.

Comment: @Jase that is the trade, they let you use the site for free because they can make money off of your content. Your content is how you "pay" for the privelege of using this site.

Comment: @Jase. Like `Oded` said. They are **Terms** & **Conditions**. What is the point in having them if users accept even though they declined the T&Cs?

Comment: @Jase *"I don't believe that just because you post something on a website, you sign away your rights to it."* I don't believe the law cares that you don't believe. You implicitly agree to a website's terms of service when you use it (I'm not talking about egregious terms like *We will take away your firstborn* or something like that). If you don't like it, don't use it. You can't use the benefit the site provides, then claim you're not bound by its rules.

Comment: The license terms allow the website to keep the data, which means that it's *legal* for them to keep that data even if the user indicates he'd like it to be deleted.  But *legal* does not mean that it's *right* or *ethical*.  If we don't raise our expectations, we'll never be treated better.

Comment: I entirely endorse Stack Exchange's policies, but this comment thread is just sad. You shouldn't be arguing from legal principles unless you've already given up on moral ones.

Comment: From a moral perspective, this resembles Wikipedia's [right to vanish](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Right_to_vanish), though theirs is rather limited in scope due to the wiki medium.

Comment: Also, don't forget international differences in data protection laws http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_to_be_forgotten