# What happens to close votes cast if you lose the close vote privilege?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

Today I've been experiencing a serial upvote (probably by a person who urgently wants to see me joining the *close vote crew*):

[image]

I well know that these upvotes will be cleaned up within the next 30 hours, and I'll lose the close voting privilege gained through these upvotes.

I thought: OK, let's do the best of it and cast some close votes on posts.

But what will happen to my close votes, when I'm going to lose that privilege? Will they be automatically retracted?

Comment: Privileges aren't taken away from you *retroactively*, so no. The close votes you cast while you have close-vote privileges will still count as close votes.

Comment: @CodyGray Interesting, so I won't loose the close voting privilege when the serial voting is reversed? If so please write that as an answer, such I can accept. (I know this is an edge case, can't judge the usefulness of my question right now)

Comment: From the title, this sounds like it would be a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254039/if-you-lose-rep-below-a-privilege-does-your-actions-in-those-areas-undo), but that one actually goes off in a different direction. It's actually closer to a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286447/what-if-i-got-upvoted-and-the-upvoter-lost-their-upvote-privilege), even though that talks about upvotes on posts, whereas you're talking about close votes. Exact same idea.

Comment: Um, I didn't say that. You would still lose the close vote privilege if your reputation dropped below the threshold. But any votes you cast while you had the privilege would still have had their effect and won't be retracted.

Comment: @CodyGray close votes are turned into close flags when the user loses the close vote privilege IIRC

Comment: @Tiny Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: @user0042 Yeah, in a comment thread on a post somewhere. Can't remember which post, or anything else remotely useful for that matter.

Comment: @Tiny Are you saying that if I have 3001 rep, cast a close vote, and then go down to 2998 rep, the close vote I cast will be retroactively converted into a flag? I don't think that's true. If so, it would be *very* weird. Although I can't prove it, I'm pretty sure that the close votes I cast when I had close voting privileges will remain close votes. What will change is what happens from then forward. At 2998 rep, I won't be able to cast any more close votes; all I can do is raise flags.

Comment: @CodyGray IIRC close votes and close flags are the same thing internally. The only difference is the rep of the caster. I _might_ be making all of this up though.

Comment: @Tiny I think you are getting it confused with flags being identical to close votes *after* you get close vote privileges. So, if you have 3001 rep, and you go through the flag dialog, you'll still end up in the exact same close dialog and cast a vote to close. I'm 99% confident that flags for non-privileged users are "RecommendClose" internally, whereas votes are votes to close.

Comment: @TinyGiant No, close votes and close flags aren't the same thing internally, rather, if you try to cast a close flag when you have the close vote privilege, it casts a close vote instead of a flag.

Comment: @Servy is that documented somewhere?

Comment: @TinyGiant I don't think it's documented anywhere, but I can confirm - when I try to cast a close _flag_ as a mod, a super-duper mod-hammer close _vote_ is cast instead, with no flag ever having existed according to the logs. That is an edge case though (because of the hammer), but I think it's the same principle.

Comment: @wizzwizz that doesn't really confirm anything. Unless you can see how those things are handled internally. I recall when I was making a suggestion with regards to changing the behavior of something around the close votes I was told that internally close votes are actually close flags. If I'm misremembering, that's fine but so far I've just been told that I'm wrong without any evidence to show that either way is correct.

Comment: Give 3000 points worth of bounty, wait for the serial upvote revert, which will not be able to affect you much anymore because you can't go below 1 Reputation, then cancel the bounties and... oh wait, nevermind...

Answer (score 28):

Losing privileges is slightly easier than you may realize.  For example, once you get the privilege to downvote at 125 rep, your *first* use of that will likely take you out of the privilege area to use it again.

That doesn't mean that the action is invalidated.  Any actions taken at a specific privilege level will remain, even if you're not at a sufficient reputation level to use it again.

Comment: _"your first use of that will likely take you out of the privilege area to use it again."_ I'm not that stoopid, sure loosing rep at downvoting answers will get you there. The question isn't if I'll lose the privilege, but what happens to the actions while I held it.

Comment: @user0042 I think Makoto's point is, if you lose the downvoting privilege by downvoting, your downvotes remain. Similarly, if you lose the close vote privilege (by losing rep in whatever way), your close votes remain.

Comment: ... and here I thought trying to downvote with 125 rep causes an infinite loop of applying the downvote, losing the privilege, reverting the vote and gaining the privilege again, which ultimately ends up crashing the internet.

Comment: @Dukeling It would crash Stack Overflow, which would give the developers enough time to quickly reset the system before all support on servers everywhere stopped due to lack of Stack Overflow. Luckily, the Stack Overflow sysadmins keep a copy of their vital information _off_ Stack Overflow.

Comment: Another sort-of common way is when people bounty away their reputation.